# When I read a value from an input tag in React, the last typed character is not read

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onchange

I am trying to read a value from a JSX  tag, using the onChange event.

When a string value is typed in the input field, I would like to store the current string in the variable **enteredFlight**, and I am using the useState hook to accomplish that.

Please see my code below:

```
import './SearchFlights.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

const SearchFlights = (props) => {
  const [enteredFlight, setEnteredFlight] = useState('');

  const flightInputHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredFlight(event.target.value);
    console.log(enteredFlight);
    props.flightInput(enteredFlight);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Search Flights</h1>
        <form>
          <label>Enter a flight number</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={flightInputHandler}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default SearchFlights;
```

However, I have noticed that the last character that is typed is not read at all. Logging the input value to the console, only yields characters up to the last character.

For instance, when I type the string 'Hello' in the input field, it only logs 'Hell' to the console.

How do I make sure that every character is saved in the enteredFlight variable as soon as it is entered?

Comment: What is `props.flightInput` doing?

Comment: props.flightInput is sending the value of enteredFlight to the parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to do it, the first one is to remove the state value, and update the props with the event directly(looks like you're not using the state for anything):

```
  const flightInputHandler = (event) => {
    props.flightInput(event.target.value);
  };
```

In that way you just going to update the props and not handle the state in this component.

If for some reason you need to have the state in this component the easiest way to keep the props up to date with the state is adding an extra useEffect that watches for the state changes like this:

```
  const [enteredFlight, setEnteredFlight] = useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
     props.flightInput(enteredFlight);
  }, [enteredFlight])

  const flightInputHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredFlight(event.target.value);
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are right about the redundant use of state. I have changed it to update the props with the event directly, and that solves my problem. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

State updates are not synchronous in React. You are logging `enteredFlight` in the handler which will show you the previous value. To properly log `enteredFlight`, you need to use the `useEffect` hook with `enteredFlight` as a dependency.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(enteredFlight);
}, [enteredFlight]);
```

`useEffect` will run every time the state `enteredFlight` has been modified. Hence, with each keypress you will be able to get your desired result.